# VS code перестал запускать файлы

Tags: python

VS code перестал запускать файлы, теперь постоянно выдает ошибку

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\Users\jorno\OneDrive\абочий стол\python\готовые\6.py'

Почему он стал обрезать путь к файлу?

```
import telebot
import time
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
al_reacts={'gratitudes':['Пасиба','thx','спс','Спс','пасиба'],
           'requests':['Дай айди','gimme id','id']}


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привет! Ты {message.from_user.username}'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mess)



@bot.message_handler(commands='id')
def get_user_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Твой ID: @{message.from_user.id}')
 
 
@bot.message_handler(commands='knopochka')
def get_user_text(message):
    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'{message.from_user.username} dasdwsdadwa:3')
    
    
@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text in al_reacts['requests']:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id ,f'Твой ID: {message.from_user.id}')
    elif message.text in al_reacts['gratitudes']:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id ,'dawda)')
    """else:
        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(0.25)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'211sa')"""
                        
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: это ошибка не VScode, а питона. Приложите код, который вы используете, для этого нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом. Код вставьте текстом

Comment: Это ошибка VScodе, после переустановки приложения ошибка пропала. До этого код работал в spyder
( в то же время не работал в VScode)
p.s. Он не запускал вообще никаких файлов, в программе не было переменных типа f=open(r'')

Comment: это исключение python, можно глянуть [здесь в доке](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError). И я всегда против переустановки, теряется чувство контроля и ты не понимаешь, что происходит

Comment: @Dmitry прикрепил код, после перезапуска ноутбука проблема вернулась((

Comment: Токен уберите и никому не показывайте

Comment: @Dmitry, не страшно, нового создать всегда могу)